# Merge all lines into one on notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have the following list:

> 32229_071
>    32225_041
>    32225_011
>    32225_011
>    32225_011

I want it to look like

> '32229_071','32225_041','32225_011','32225_011','32225_011'

How do I do this in Notepad++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G)(.+)(?:(\R)|\z)`
- Replace with: `'$1'(?2,:)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:^|\G)        # non capture group, beginning of line or restart from last match position
(.+)            # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
(?:             # non capture group
  (\R)          # group 2, any kind of linebreak
 |              # OR
  \z            # end of file
)               # end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
'$1'            # content of grop 1  between single quotes
(?2,:)          # conditional replace, if group 2 exists then a comma else nothing
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Hi, and if i want to add () between numbers, how can i do?

Comment: Like this, for example

('32282-P'),('32814-P'),('32883-O'),('32839-C'),('32867-X'),('32841-F'),('32886-D')

Comment: @dvazantunes: In the replace box, type: `\('$1'\)(?2,:)`. Don't forget to escape the parenthesis, it's specific to Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to replace (ctrl+h)
2. Search for *\r\n*
3. Replace *,*
4. Check Extended (left bottom)
5. Add first and last quote

And replace!

[image]

Comment: I apologize but I misplaced the question, can you check again this time considering the question of quotes please?

Comment: You should add the quotes before and after the comma. Then only the first comma and last comma of the total line should be added. Does that work?

Comment: @DanielAntunes well then replace the line break with `','` instead, and add the single `'` in the front and back of the whole thing manually?

Comment: What about Linux EOL? Why two steps when a single one is enough?